# How to provide parameters in Koin dry run test?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, koin

My `ViewModel` needs `repository` & `genre` through constructor. `repository` is provided by Koin  & `genre` string is provided from activity

```
// Main app module
val MovieListModule: Module = applicationContext {

    // provide repository
    bean {
        DummyMovieListRepository() as MovieListRepository
    }

    // provides ViewModel
    viewModel { params: ParameterProvider ->
        MovieListViewModel(respository = get(), genre = params["key.genre"])
    }
}

//Module list for startKoin()
val appModules = listOf(MovieListModule)

//in activity
val viewModel = getViewModel<MovieListViewModel> {
   mapOf("key.genre" to "Action / Drama")
}

// dry run test which fails
class KoinDryRunTest : KoinTest {
    @Test
    fun dependencyGraphDryRun() {
        startKoin(list = appModules)
        dryRun()
    }
}

// some error log 
org.koin.error.MissingParameterException: Parameter 'key.genre' is missing
    at org.koin.dsl.context.ParameterHolder.get(ParameterHolder.kt:46)
org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create bean Factory[class=io.github.karadkar.popularmovies.MovieListViewModel, binds~(android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel)] due to error :
    org.koin.error.MissingParameterException: Parameter 'key.genre' is missing
```

here Koin (v 0.9.3) injection inactivity works as expected but the dry run test fails as it can't find parameter `key.genre`. [Check full error-log](https://pastebin.com/Qr9Uw9fq)

Is there any  way to mock/provide `key.genre` value to dry run test?

[full app source](https://github.com/karadkar/PopularMovies-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Arnaud Giuliani](https://twitter.com/arnogiu/status/1030170808507949057) pointed on twitter. `dryRun` accepts lambda function for parameters

```
class KoinDryRunTest : KoinTest {
    @Test
    fun dependencyGraphDryRun() {
        startKoin(list = appModules)
        dryRun() {
            mapOf("key.genre" to "dummy string")
        }
    }
}
```